# Finding link button from one of a Data List from a Grid View

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a Grid View and a Data list(bot contains some of the columns and link button respectively) how can i find the Data list  Link button Control  by clicking on a link button in the Grid view (Grid View Data is Generated by the Data list link button and botha have the same Data Key mentioned) the related code i have is this

```
protected void Gird1_Click(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    Label id = (Label)Grid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_PID");

    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["DataTable"];
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
           if (dt.Rows[i]["P_ID"].ToString() == id.Text)
            {
                dt.Rows[i].Delete();
            }
        }
    }
   // LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)DataList1.Items[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lnk_Add"); 

    LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)DataList1.  [Convert.ToInt32(id.Text)];//FindControl("lnk_Add"); 
    lnkbtn.Enabled = true;
    ViewState["DataTable"] = dt;
    Grid1.DataSource = ViewState["DataTable"];
    Grid1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the same name to those 2 link buttons
and onclick of link button in gridview

```
{
   linkbutton lnkGridview=(linkbutton)sender;
   foreach(datalistitem item in datalist1.items)
  {
     linkbutton lnkDatalist=(linkbutton)item.findcontrol(lnkGridview.ClientID);
  }

}
```

Comment: i am Getting this error in response 

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'."

on this line 

"linkbutton lnkGridview=(linkbutton)sender;"

Comment: this is because i am using "GridViewDeleteEventArgs" not "eventargs"

Comment: i understood ur problem u used  inbuilt gridview deltecommands.

Comment: if we use item template in gridview and datalist what ever i gave it'll work so i am sorry i don't know it

Comment: Label id = (Label)Grid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_PID"); foreach(datalistitem item in datalist1.items)
  {
     linkbutton lnkDatalist=(linkbutton)item.findcontrol("linkbuttonDatalistID");
  } u can try this if you know the particular link buttonID

Comment: that is for deleting rows in grid view

Comment: great its working , but what is it doing is taking all the link button from all the rows as i have binded the link button is there any way through which i can get the specific row and its link button

Answer (score 0):

Finally....

```
    int increment = 0;
    int count = DataList1.Items.Count-1;
    while (increment<=count)
    {


        Label datalist_id = (Label)DataList1.Items[increment].FindControl("lbl_PID");
        if (id.Text == datalist_id.Text)
        {
            LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)DataList1.Items[increment].FindControl("lnk_Add");
            lnkbtn.Enabled = true;
        }
        increment = increment + 1;
    }
```